# Still on Old Employers' Team page on their website

Tags: employees, rights

It's nearly 2 months since I left my previous employer, and I'm still displayed on their site as en employee on their 'Team' page.

I have sent them a polite email asking for removal but I've basically been 'fobbed off'.

I don't want my reputation to be damaged by being associated with the company; and I fear that they're still keeping me on there to 'keep up appearances' with their clients. I'm not sure what my options are, but I would like to be removed from their site as soon as possible.

For reference, this is in the UK.

Comment: Related, though more serious: [My ex-employer is sending emails to customers in my name](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50642/my-ex-employer-is-sending-emails-to-customers-in-my-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not sure what my options are, but I would like to be removed from
>   their site as soon as possible.

- You could hound them with emails and phone calls until you are no longer displayed on the Team page, copying anyone and everyone in the company who you feel could help move your request along. I'd go as far up the corporate ladder as I could. (the "squeaky wheel" approach)
- You could get your attorney to send them a letter
- You could go to court to force them to remove you
- You could ignore it and wait for it to eventually go away

I'm not sure how it worked in your company, but in my company the "Team" page was controlled by the Marketing group, who were extremely slow to react. Two months was nothing. They meant no malice, it just wasn't high on their priority list. Your mileage may vary.

If I were really concerned and wanted to be removed quickly, I'd start with the first approach. I'd also keep copies of everything I sent in case I needed to escalate.

Comment: There's the milder version of option 1: send an email about once a week copying in someone you know is good at actually getting tasks done like an efficient admin.